# give users the ability to view, edit or delete data in profile page

Tags: database, wordpress, user-accounts, user-profile

On the "My Account" page of your website, certain users are able to log in to their profile and upload up to 5 invoices. They will also need to provide additional information, such as their tax ID, invoice date, invoice number, and invoice amount.
Now, I would like to give these users the ability to view their uploaded invoices and edit or delete them as needed directly from the "My Account" page.

I've used the "Contact Form 7" plugin to create this form, which sends the invoices to an email address. I should mention that I use "Manufacturing Industry Pro" wordpress theme.
How can I give this ability to users? please explain me step by step. I would prefer not using plugins.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you *would like to give these users the ability to view their uploaded invoices and edit or delete them* without indicating the file type, mime type, format or other features embedded or associated with these invoice documents. Do you allow users to upload any document file type? Your request might be more complicated than it appears. This plugin [PDF Forms Filler for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pdf-forms-for-contact-form-7/) might do what you want. But, even this might require external web APIs or purchases of PDF processing software for the server.

Comment: What you tried so far? Do you want to use Ajax and where do you want so save the data, for example in the user meta? Are you able to create a custom plugin? Unfortunately this is not a "do the work for me" platform. Make some research and test some code. If you have any probems, users will be able to help you with that.